# What is the general term for algorithms that handle receiving requests?

Tags: algorithm, throttling, debouncing

Stuff like debouncing, the leaky bucket algorithm, throttling, etc.

I really want to know more about these and I want to find similar algorithms that handle receiving multiple requests at a time in a server.

Comment: [Rate limiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_limiting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithms you mentioned are used for **rate limiting**.